# python add_argument parameters definition

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a sample OCR program to extract digits from the business card.
I am not sure I understand the usage of "-i", "-d","--image", "--digits".
Also what is the use of "Options" in line 22 and 27. Thanks in advance
Here is the code:

```
# USAGE
# python ocr_digits.py --image apple_support.png
# python ocr_digits.py --image apple_support.png --digits 0

# import the necessary packages
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--digits", type=int, default=1,
                help="whether or not *digits only* OCR will be performed")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the input image, convert it from BGR to RGB channel ordering,
# and initialize our Tesseract OCR options as an empty string
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
options = ""

# check to see if *digit only* OCR should be performed, and if so,
# update our Tesseract OCR options
if args["digits"] > 0:
    options = "outputbase digits"

# OCR the input image using Tesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(rgb, config=options)
print(text)
```

Comment: `options` is just some value that `image_to_string` accepts as its `config` keyword argument. Its only relation to `argparse` is that `-d` can be used to determine what the value of `options` will be.

Comment: Thank you @chepner .